# How to update multiple values in a SQL database from a 'select multiple' box in asp?

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

I'm setting up a select multiple box to allow multiple values to be added to a database at once, and using the below code:

```
<select name="add" style="width: 100%; height: 100px" multiple>
                <%
                    do until rsCategory.bof or rsCategory.eof = true

                    %>
                    <option value="<%=rsCategory("catID")%>"><%=rsCategory("Cat")%></option>
                <%
                rsCategory.movenext
                loop %>
                </select>
```

This code works just fine displaying the multiple select, and is a twist on an existing dropdown box I have for a single select I have. The trouble I'm having is converting the below code to input the multiple values into the SQL database, as opposed to just one value:

```
<!-- #include virtual = "includes/coredataconn.asp "  -->
<!-- #include virtual = "includes/cleansql.asp"  -->
<%

if session("customername") <> "admin" then response.redirect "logout.asp"
accID = cleansql(request.form("accountID")) 
catId = cleansql(request.form("add"))


set rsNU = server.createobject("adodb.recordset")
sqNU = "SELECT * FROM categoriestable WHERE ((([AccountNo])='" & accID & "') OR accountID='" & accID & "');"
rsNU.open sqNU, cnnCore, 3, 3
rsNU(catId) = "Y"
rsNU.update
response.Redirect "../admin_categories.asp?account=" & accID

%>
```

I would have imagined some sort of for loop would work but I'm struggling to get it right. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you use browser dev tools or your favorite network trace to show what the POST body is when you submit this form? Also consider removing the c# tag.

Comment: `cleansql()`, that made me chuckle. Workarounds for functionality that has already existed in ADODB for 20+ years.

Comment: @Lankymart cleansql() is unfortunately a remnant of the previous dev's work. I'm slowly working towards getting away from it

Comment: Did you check what the catId-variable looks like after the cleaning? For example if it looks like "45,56,67" you can do a `split(catId, ",")` and then do a `foreach`-loop with an UPDATE-statement for each value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you cleansql function does, but at least it shows you're aware of SQL injection risks, so I'll skip that part...

A "multiple" select returns its values in the format "15,23,45,28", for example.

So you might use the following :

```
accID = cleansql(request.form("accountID")) 
catId = cleansql(request.form("add"))

sqNU = "UPDATE categoriestable SET whatever_field = 'Y' WHERE (AccountNo='" & accID & "' OR accountID='" & accID & "') AND catID IN (" & catId & ")"
cnnCore.Execute sqNU
```

If your catID field is numeric, this should work as is, otherwise you'll have to add code that formats your catId contents as "'15','23','45','28'"

Comment: Aware of the risk, but still choosing the wrong approach to "solve" it.

Comment: The catID field is indeed numeric, however this doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Well, what does a response.write of your sqNU return?

Comment: @ChrisBE `cleansql()` will likely ruin the delimited value list.

Comment: That's my guess too, but hard to say without the actual output...